# Escape an '&' for a TabPage tab

Tags: c#-3.0

I want the TabPage to display "M & P" in its tab.
The tab displays "M && P".
I am using VS 2008 for Windows Forms applications.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's a character encoding problem?

Answer (score 0):

TagPage .Text accepts a single ampersand.

You have to put 3 ampersands in to get 2 ampersands out.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single `&` character.

Comment: I am using a single '&' as in "M & P". I want the result to only show one '&' as in "M & P" but I am getting two of them "&&" as in "M && P".

Comment: Same here, single ampersand.

Is it the Windows TabPage or a 3rd party TabPage?

Comment: The version is XP Pro with SP 3